# how to rewrite any request for php file to main page in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, path, url-rewriting

im wondering  how Rewrite path like this www.domain.com/pages/article/
to www.domain.com

i did it but CSS files has changed path too

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^index.php$
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com/ [L]
```

Comment: Your question title and question text doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Add exclusions for those in separate rewrite conditions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^index.php$
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com/ [L]
```